# mysqli never returns anything

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

As part of a PHP web application, I'm querying a MySQL database using mysqli and prepared statements.

I've used exactly the same code on a few queries and it works, but on one particular query, it always returns an empty record set. I've run exactly the same query from the MySQL command line, and it correctly returns the result. I've checked the parameters being passed in, and they're fine.

I've spent the best part of a day trying to figure out why I'm always getting an empty record set with no errors or warnings. I've got PHP's errors set to display on the page, and I've got them set to E_ALL|E_STRICT. I still don't get any warnings or errors.

I've tried all the obvious things, like making sure I can actually connect to the database, checking the parameters that are being passed in, and making sure the row I'm trying to return actually exists in the database. I've had var_dump()s and die()s all over the page to check what's coming back, and it's always a legitimate, but empty, recordset.

```
function salt() {
   return("I've removed my salt from this sample code");
}

function openDatabase() {
   $conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "username", "password", "database")
      or die("Error: Could not connect to database.");
   return($conn);
}

function checkUserCredentials($username, $password) {
   $goodPassword = md5(salt().$username.$password);

   $conn = openDatabase();
   $query = $conn->stmt_init();

   $query->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? AND passwordHash = ?")
      or die('Problem with query');

   $query->bind_param("ss", $username, $goodPassword)
      or die('Error binding parameters');

   $query->execute() or die("Could not execute");
   $query->bind_result($col1) or die ("Could not bind result");

   if ($col1 !== 0) {
      die("Authentication Complete");
   } else {
      die("Authentication Failure! Number of Rows: ".$query->num_rows." Username: " . $username . " Password Hash: " . $goodPassword);
   }
}
```

Any feedback is appreciated. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but if I didn't shave my head I'd be tearing my hair out right now.

Thanks

Comment: What is exactly the error you see on screen, I mean do you sea any text from the above `die` statements?

Comment: 1. return is a language built-in statement, don't use paranthesis on it, it's not a function. - 2. You don't return any result from checkUserCredentials.

Comment: I get nothing from any of my die() statements. Also, I did return true/false in checkUserCredentials, but I commented them out to debug with the die() statements.

Comment: All that PHP code returns is "Authentication Failure! Number of Rows: 0 Username: my_email@address Password Hash: 95b9947ba38b137cbbf21e98f1c040cb" I've checked, and my_email@address and that password hash ARE in the table.

Comment: I've rolled-back your edit adding an answer in your question. I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own answer). 
When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the mysqli library (I usually use PDO which provides a very similar cross platform API) so I can't immediately see any problem. However, you might try watching the mysqld log. See here for info:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

By tailing the log, you should be able to see the exact query that was submitted.

One final note, I notice you're using a fixed salt value. Wouldn't it be better to generate this value randomly each time you need it and then store it in the users table? Generally, a salt is not intended to be secret, it's just there to prevent people precomputing tables of passwords using the hash algorithm that you use.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I used tail -f on my mysql log, and the query is coming through OK. Copying and pasting it into mysql does return what I want, but PHP/mysqli still returns an empty set. As for the salt, I will make it more secure with a user-specific hash before the application goes live.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm just clutching at straws here but you might try print_r($col1) or even print_r($query) just to see exactly what's in each data structure. It might just give you an "aha!" moment.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into similar issues, it *really* helps if you run fetch() on your mysqli_stmt object.

In my code above, the solution looks like this:

```
$query->bind_result($col1) or die ("Could not bind result");

$query->fetch(); // <--- How could I forget to do this?

if ($col1 !== 0) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

<sub>*Added on behalf of OP*</sub>